# How to change Instantiated Objects Font Colour in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005, colors, environment

I know the colours are changed in Environment > Fonts and Colors but I haven't found out which Display Item the object is.

Can someone please tell how I can colour the following code:

> lblMessage.Text = "You have successfully answered my question!"

I have the string coloured pink, I would like the lblMessage purple and the .Text a light green.

For me the darker the colour the less it will "change". I won't often change object names, I'll more often change properties and am always changing strings - although I have another question about this that I'll post later.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Environment > Fonts and Colors > Display Item**s and change

- Identifier
- String

> I was hoping that their is I can be
>   more specific with the colours - if
>   their isn't then that's an acceptable
>   answer - just disappointing for me.

Yeah, I don't think you can do that. :)

Comment: @ John

Thanks John but that changes lot's of things from Function and Sub names to parameters.

I was hoping that I can be more specific with the colours - if this isn't possible then that's an acceptable answer - just disappointing for me.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you use a 3rd party addin like [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com).  It lets you assign different colors to classes, variables, macros and functions (among other features).